# How to render field in hook_form_alter?

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying to show a user profile field in node form.

```
function mymodule_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
        $form['myfield'] = array(
            '#markup' => drupal_render(field_view_field('user', $account, 'field_myfield'));
        );
}
```

`field_view_field()` is not returning any thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a definition for the `$account` object anywhere in your code. You're probably missing the following lines before your call to `field_view_field()`:

```
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
```

Also, and this might sound stupid, but make sure you replace `FORM_ID` with the actual ID of your form :)

Comment: The global $user object is not the same as the user entity, it contains no fields, which means it won't work in this case (calling field_views_field() with it).

Comment: @Bojan You beat me to it by about 5 seconds...I just corrected that

Comment: Thanks for the ans. I missed the line global $user; while pasting the code of course I am using form_id instead of FORM_ID.

Answer (score 3):

Question is, the profile field of which user? The node author, or the current user?

In both cases you need to fetch the $account you are trying to pass to field_view_field.

For the current user:

```
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
```

For the node author:

```
$account = user_load($form_state['node']->uid);
```